# Trek Checkpoint ALR 4 (2021)

Tags: shimano, conversion, gravel

I have a Shimano GRX RX400 long cage on my 2x10 Trek Checkpoint ALR 4 (2021).  Can I change to an 11 Speed Cassette, GRX 600 Right Shifter and 11 speed chain to convert it to a 2x11 speed drive train. keeping the front and left shifter as is.  $350 would upgrade me to 11 speed.

Comment: I'm not going to answer because I haven't done the mismatch in this direction, but what does work is using the 11-speed RDs as replacements in the "new" actuation ratio 10-speed groups, 4700 and RX400. I suspect you could do it the other way without issue.

Comment: One consideration is that the 400 and 600 series’ brifters may be different shapes. It may feel weird to have two differently shaped brifters.

Comment: Are single shifters even sold? I've seen only pairs

Comment: @ojs Of course they are. If one is broken, they are way too expensive to buy a needless other half of a pair.

Comment: @VladimirF from manufacturer's perspective it's a perfect opportunity to force customers to buy something they don't need. If manufacturers cared about the customer's costs, they'd make the shifters repairable and sell spare parts (Campagnolo used to have every part available as spare, but not any more)

Comment: @ojs  It really isn't. Could have been, but isn't. Just go to your favourite e-shop and buy a single shifter of your choice. There is no point hypothesizing what the vendors could achieve if they only sold them in pairs. They just don't.

Comment: Citing 4 comments above: "I've seen only pairs"

Comment: @ojs You looked wrong.